# Unnecessary line breaks in a div text

Tags: html, css

I need to hide a newsletter form when the user press the sign up button ("Cadastrar" in portuguese) and this is already happening as you may check on my [website](http://www.madcloset.com.br). However, the success message is rendered with unnecessary line breaks. Why?

I need to fill the entire height of the footer (without fixing the height in the child div, if possible), but the text should be vertically centered in the red box.

You'll probably find easy to check the problem by going to my website, filling the email address field and clicking the button bellow, but here is the HTML rendered there.

```
<div id="mc4wp-form-1" class="form mc4wp-form mc4wp-form-3571 mc4wp-ajax mc4wp-form-success">
    <form method="post" lpformnum="1" _lpchecked="1">
        <input type="email" name="EMAIL" class="text" placeholder="Seu email" required="">
        <input type="submit" class="bt" value="Cadastrar"><span class="mc4wp-ajax-loader" style="display: none; vertical-align: middle; height: 16px; width: 16px; border: 0px; margin-left: 5px; background: url(/img/ajax-loader.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat;"></span>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
            <input type="text" name="_mc4wp_required_but_not_really" value="" tabindex="-1">
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="mc4wp-response">
        <div class="mc4wp-alert mc4wp-success">Obrigado, seu cadastro foi efetuado com sucesso! Por favor verifique seu e-mail.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: How it looks]

Here is an attempt to reproduce on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/julianonunes/a597Lydc/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution add `float: left;` property to `mc4wp-error` selector

```
.mc4wp-error {
    background-color: #FEE7ED;
    color: #F41952;
    border-color: #F41952;
    float: left; <----Add this
}
```

Reason why text is breaking

Newsletter, input and button pushing and breaking the text

[image]

Remove `float:left` from

```
footer form {
    width: 100% !important;
    float: left !important; <---Remove this
}

.mc4wp-alert {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

[image]

Mobile view and CSS changes `max-width:480px`

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    footer form {
        float: left !important; <---Remove this
    }

    .mc4wp-alert {
        position: absolute;
        top: inherit;
        min-height: 200px;
        bottom: -90px;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you fill with a valid email format it won't use this class, and adding float: left to mc4wp-success makes the div to be positioned below the form.

Comment: That's not what my partner wants.

Comment: is the warning text is plugin built-in warning or you customize it?

Comment: It's created by the mailchimp for wordpress plugin, but it is customized via CSS.

Comment: Removing `float: left !important` from `<form>` also made the div to go down, below the form.

Comment: check answer now and lemme know if its fixed it or not

Comment: On desktop it's perfect, but on mobile the position is wrong. http://i.imgur.com/RJgmbzV.png

Comment: use media queries, you have to define the `.mc4wp-alert` properties in media queries according to screen size, in this css file `responsive.css` or as you are using WP, you can put in custom css

Comment: check example for mobile css

Comment: Now it's perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you change:

```
.mc4wp-alert {
  ...
  ...
  position: relative;
}
```

to `position: fixed;`, you will find that the space is actually occupied by the email text-box and the button. The solution is to use `position: absolute;`. I tested it in Chrome and IE11.